# Code to find out the number of triplets which lead to a sum less than or equal to threshold is giving a wrong output

Tags: c++

I am solving C++ coding problems and I have come across the problem "Find the count of triplets given the following 2 conditions- who sum to a given threshold value(the threshold value is an integer) and the triplets should be `a[i]<a[j]<a[k]` where `a` is the array and `i`,'j','k' are the indices of the array (for illustration purpose). 
What I did-

```
 #include <cmath>
 #include <cstdio>
 #include <vector>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <algorithm>
 using namespace std;

 int threeSum(vector<int>& nums, int threshold); //function declaration

int main() {
int result, threshold;
cin>>threshold; //entered by user
vector<int> nums; //array which contains values
for(int m = 0 ; m< nums.size() ; m++)
    nums.push_back(m);
result = threeSum(nums, threshold);
cout<<result;
return 0;
}

int threeSum(vector<int>& nums, int threshold) {
   // vector<vector<int>> result;
    int count = 0, threshold;  
    if(nums.empty() || nums.size()<=2)
        return 0;
    sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size() - 2; i++) {
        int a = nums[i];
        if(a > threshold) break;
        if (i > 0 && a == nums[i - 1]) continue;
        for (long j = i + 1, k = nums.size() - 1; j < k;) {
            int b = nums[j];
            int c = nums[k];
            int value = a + b + c;
            if (value <= threshold) {
                count++;
                while (j<k && b == nums[++j]);
                while (j < k &&c == nums[--k]);
            } else if (value > 0) {
                k--;
            } else {
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

My output should give the number of such triplets, but I am getting 0 as an output. For example, my input is say 7(threshold), followed by 1,2,4,6 (the vector elements), my output should say 1, since there is one such triplet (1,2,4) which adds upto or less than the given threshold value, whereas it says 0

The final working code, after receiving help from many fellow StackOverflow members is as follows

```
 #include <vector>
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

int threeSum(const vector<int>& nums, int threshold); 

int main() {
int threshold = 7;
vector<int> nums = {1,2,4,6};
int result = threeSum(nums, threshold);
cout << result;
}

int threeSum(const vector<int>& nums, int threshold)
{
if (nums.size() < 3)
    return 0;

int count = 0;      
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nums.size() - 2; i++)
{
    if (nums[i] < nums[i+1] && nums[i+1] < nums[i+2]
        && nums[i] + nums[i+1] + nums[i+2] <= threshold)
    {
        count += 1;
    }
}
return count;
}
```

Comment: So, does it work? Where does it fail? Please describe what exactly you are requesting we look at.

Comment: @John3136, I am sorry, I forgot to ask the question, I have edited my question now.

Comment: If the result depends on the ordering of the input, sorting that input doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: The size of an empty vector is 0, so you are adding zero elements to the empty vector before calling threeSum...

Answer (score 2):

Every element of nums is greater equal zero.

Therfor a = nums[i] is greater equal zero.

Therefor you leave the for loop at

```
if(a > 0) break;
```

Maybe it should be

```
if(a > threshold) break;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But it doesn't seem to work. Also, it is not necessary that every element in the vector should be greater than 0, for example, if I have a vector with elements -1,0,1,2,-1,-4 and the threshold is 0, my output should be 2 since there are 2 triplets namely (-1,0,1) and (-1,-1,2)

Answer (score 1):

The initial problem is (and you compiler should have warned you - please study how to set that up, or if you ignored it, please don't ignore it in future) that `threshold` in `threeSum()` in not initialised at all. Try this instead:

```
result = threeSum(nums,threshold);
```

and

```
int threeSum(vector<int>& nums, int threshold)
```

I'll leave you to work out the other details!

Comment: I was using an online compiler and didn't receive any warning. I tried including the 'threshold' parameter, but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Ahh, online compilers... You really should get a free local compiler instead as debugging will be much, much easier. Anyway, I also see `if(a > 0) break;` - that will basically ignore everything as it is always true.

Comment: I tried that but doesn't seem to help. I am allowed to have negative numbers, Use case- if I have a vector with elements -1,0,1,2,-1,-4 and the threshold is 0, my output should be 2 since there are 2 triplets namely (-1,0,1) and (-1,-1,2)

Comment: @Smr (-1,-1,2) is not a triplet in that input, and there are no equal numbers in a valid triplet.

Comment: @molbdnilo, Yes I got it. Understood that. Thanks again

Comment: @molbdnilo, I think there is some problem in the code, when the input is 1,2,3,4, and the threshold is 7, the output should be 2 since triplets are [1,2,3] and [1,2,4], but I am getting 1 as the output

Comment: @Smr [1,2,4] – (a[i], a[i+1], a[i+3] when i is 0) – is not a triplet.

Comment: @molbdnilo, My bad, I haven't explained the question properly. I want all triplets to be counted, not just consecutive ones.